# TSQL Naming conventions ~ What's this naming convention called?

Tags: t-sql, naming-conventions

Given that I'm using TSQL, what's the name of this style of naming?

```
\\servername\instance.database.schema.table
```

and what other items can be inserted in place of .dbo. in the previous naming instance? how does one go about creating those alternatives? links to answers welcome

Also, how would one refer to a job on the server instead of a table or a sproc?

My intention is for when I write up my work for documentation (say when I'm closing out my FogBugz ticket or something) then I want to be able to at least **sound** like I know what I'm doing `;)`

*(updated per links and comments)*

Comment: \*lol\* at the justification :-D

Comment: Is this what you're after: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177563.aspx

Comment: @OMG Ponies ~ I suppose so. Just curious if there's a name for the things I use really. Nice to be able to say "what's that {name} for the object you're using?" instead of groping with "what's the IP/servername and database where the object you're using is?"

Comment: Three & four part name are the most common references I've come across, but as you can see - there's lots of shorthand alternatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three & four part name are the most common references I've come across, but [as you can see - there's lots of shorthand alternatives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177563.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The `dbo` is the schema. You can create new schemas and assign db objects to the schema.

Answer (score 1):

That is the entire path. If you're hitting a table within your **default schema** (this is dbo by default) all you need is table. (SELECT * FROM Addresses)

If you're hitting a table on a schema other than the user's default (or you want to protect yourself from future changes) then you'll put Schema.Table. (SELECT * FROM Customers.Addresses)

If you're looking to hit a table on a different database within the same server, you will need to put DatabaseName.Schema.Table. (SELECT * FROM ProductionDB.Customers.Addresses)

Finally, if you're looking to a hit a table on a different server all-together, you need the full path. These machines must also have a server-link, AFAIK.

Comment: Ok, but is there a name for the path? In web parlance we term them URL or URI. In db's?

Comment: OMG Ponies' comment has a link where they call it the four part name. Vote up his comment if it's the answer :)

Comment: @drachenstern: I'd call it a "fully qualified object name" but I have no idea if that is the official moniker for it.

Comment: ~ Yeah, I think that's as good as I'm going to get. I don't know if there's a better name. ~~ @Tomalak ~ Yeah, so far I think either "fully qualified name" or "four part name" is all I'm going to be able to get.  I can let @OMG Ponies post an answer and I can accept, or I can accept one of the others given. I'm open to any and all of those options.

Comment: Definitely give it to whichever answer you're going with! Have OMG or Tomalak post an answer and accept it :).